# Why am I able to edit the value of a locked cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of cells in Excel that I would like to prevent the user from editing.  I have marked the cells as locked in the `Format Cells...`->`Protection` menu, and I have protected the sheet with a password with the `Review` -> `Protect Sheet` button.  However, I am still able to edit some of the cells as if they were unprotected.

Why am I able to edit the values of locked cells in a protected Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell protections can be overwritten by the whitelisted ranges in the `Review`->`Allow Users to Edit Ranges` menu.  You will be able to edit the cells in any ranges listed there, even if they are protected.

It looks like this in Microsoft Excel 2013.

[image: Menu]

[image: Popup]